# Can I attempt to open a MySQL Connection in a catch?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this method:

```
static void DbConnect()
{
    // Connects to the Db using a simplified Connection string.
    try
    {
        mySqlConnect = new MySqlConnection("server=" + Setup_Controller.server + ";uid=root;");
        mySqlConnect.Open();
    }
    // If a password is required, tries again using the password provided.
    catch (MySqlException) 
    {
        mySqlConnect = new MySqlConnection("server=" + Setup_Controller.server + ";uid=root;password='" + Setup_Controller.password + "';");
        mySqlConnect.Open();
    }
}
```

However every time it catches an exception, it won't load open the connection because of the current exception caused by the first connection attempt. I am beginning to wonder whether it's because the try/catch is not allowing the program to continue, because there is an unhandled exception in play?

Comment: Post the details of the exception you're getting.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the 2nd connection attempt fails as well?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline "Unable to connect to any specified MySQL Hosts". I believe that is because the MySQL connection requires a password, which is why the first connection fails.

Comment: @JamesBlond I hadn't really thought of that. I'm starting to think that it might be better to put them in two different try/catch blocks and place the second one in an `if (MsqlConnect = false) {}`

Comment: Ok, so why don't you specify a password the first time around?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline That allows for the case where a password is not required. Is `server=server_name;uid=root;pwd=;` a valid connection string? Where `pwd=;`?

Comment: If your username is hardcoded to `root` then you will always need a password. I'm not even sure it's possible to use the `root` account without a password. However, I would go with Ben's suggestion of putting a `catch` after the second attempt.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline so is my guess that the second connection attempt is refusing to fire properly because it's detecting an error?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Did you try `try-catch`-ing it?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline the program crashes when it attempts to open the second connection. I haven't `try/catch`-ing it yet because that seems like fairly solid evidence something isn't working properly. However I have tested the full connection string (the second one) elsewhere with no issues.

Comment: Ok, well I assume you know for a fact that the user account in question needs a password, yes? Therefore, just modify this code to `try` with a password the first time, then in the `catch` output the error. So only attempt a SINGLE time. Once we've narrowed down what the problem is, we can work on getting it back into this state where it tries once without a password, then again with.
When you say it crashes, what's the error?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline I have tried connecting without a password, but it catches the error, saying "Unable to connect to MySQL Hosts". This is because I have a password already set up on the root account. If I use the correct password, it connects without an issue.

Comment: Again-- what is the error you're getting when you attempt to establish a connection the second time, *with* a password?

Comment: In the catch block? "Unable to connect to MySQL Hosts". In the try block? None. It connects with no issues

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use this method, you need to first close your connection before you can use it again.

```
static void DbConnect()
{
    // Connects to the Db using a simplified Connection string.

   try
   {
       mySqlConnect = new MySqlConnection("server=" + Setup_Controller.server + 
        ";uid=root;");
        mySqlConnect.Open();
    }
// If a password is required, tries again using the password provided.
catch (MySqlException) 
{

      //make sure connection is close
     if(mySqlConnection != null) 
           mySqlConnect.Close();
 }
 /* i don't know what this class looks like but most data class expose some method 
    to see if the connection is still open or close. If there is not an IsOpen check
    for IsClose or something like this 
 */
 if(!mySqlConnect.IsOpen()) 
 {
   try 
   {

         mySqlConnect = new MySqlConnection("server=" + Setup_Controller.server + 
       ";uid=root;password='" + Setup_Controller.password + "';");
         mySqlConnect.Open();
    }
    catch (MySqlException) 
    {
      //make sure connection is close
      mySqlConnect.Close();
    }
```

}

Comment: Do you really need to close it when it fails to open (i.e. the open call throws an exception)? Not impossible, but sounds very odd to me.

Comment: This is definitely looking like a more solid programming solution. :) Just a question, do you *why* the second connection doesn't want to open (in my original example)?

Comment: My only guess is that the second connection is throwing an error too.